# python function conditional return

Tags: python

When using a conditional return, if you attempt to return more than one value from function, the function behaves erratically with regard to the actual return value.

```
def test_function(x,y, diagnostic:bool=False):
    w = x*y
    z = []
    if diagnostic: 
        z = [w,w*2]
    return z, w if diagnostic else w

print(test_function(3,4)) # output tuple ([],12)

# lets switch order of the return from z,w to w,z

def test_function(x,y, diagnostic:bool=False):
    w = x*y
    z = []
    if diagnostic: 
        z = [w,w*2]
    return w,z if diagnostic else w

print(test_function(3,4)) # output tuple (12,12) 

# lets try retun the diagnostic value itself to see what function things is happening

def test_function(x,y, diagnostic:bool=False):
    w = x*y
    z = []
    if diagnostic: 
        z = [w,w*2]
    return diagnostic if diagnostic else w

print(test_function(3,4)) # returns 12, so diagnostic is retuning false

# rewrite conditional to "if not"
def test_function(x,y, diagnostic:bool=False):
    w = x*y
    z = []
    if diagnostic: 
        z = [w,w*2]
    return w if not diagnostic else w,z

print(test_function(3,4)) # returns (12, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If returning multiple values in a conditional return, the values must be explicitly returned as a tuple due to operator precedence:

```
def test_function(x,y, diagnostic:bool=False):
            w = x*y
            z = []
            if diagnostic: 
                z = [w,w*2]
            return (z, w) if diagnostic else w
          
print(test_function(3,4)) # returns 12
print(test_function(3,4, diagnostic=False)) # returns (12, [12, 24])
w, z = test_function(3,4, diagnostic=True)
print(w) # returns 12
print(z) # returns [12,24]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is operator precedence: `,` has lower precedence than `... if ... else ...`, so what you actually wrote is like `return z, (w if diagnostic else w)`, or in the second function, it's like `return w, (z if diagnostic else w)`.

The hint for this is that `diagnostic` is `False` but you're still returning a pair of values.

For the behaviour you want, you should write `return (z, w) if diagnostic else w`. Note that the brackets here are *not* needed to make it a tuple - it is a tuple either way - the brackets are to specify precedence.